# Call Back Editable IFrames Changes into Codemirror

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/aNirEnUB/3/edit

I've been experimenting with [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) for a bit, and today I decided to make the iframe editable, but haven't figured out a way to call back the changes I make to the iframe via change and apply those changes directly to Codemirror.

Is this possible?

**JavaScript/JQuery**:

```
var delay;

// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    mode: 'text/html',
    tabMode: 'indent',
  styleActiveLine: true,
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    autoCloseTags: true
});

// Live preview
editor.on("change", function() {
    clearTimeout(delay);
    delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
});

function updatePreview() {
    var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
    preview.open();
    preview.write(editor.getValue());
    preview.close();
}
setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);

// Make the preview editable
window.onload = function() {
  preview.document.designMode = 'On';
};

// Update the Editor Code from Preview Edit
preview.on('change', function() {
  clearTimeout(delay);
  delay = setTimeout(updateEditor, 300);
});

function updateEditor() {
  var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
  var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
  preview.open();
  editor.setValue(preview.body.innerHTML());
  preview.close();
}
setTimeout(updateEditor, 300);
```

**HTML**:

```
<textarea id="code" name="code"><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>HTML5 canvas demo</title>
<style>p {font-family: monospace;}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Canvas pane goes here:</p>
  <canvas id=pane width=300 height=200></canvas>

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('pane');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(250,0,0)';
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);

    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5)';
    context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
  </script>
</body>
</html></textarea>

<iframe id="preview"></iframe>
```

Comment: Just curious, what you expect If user change the html code in iframe ?

Comment: I'm just experimenting. I haven't been able to figure out how to direct the code from the iframe to Codemirror after the document has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/aNirEnUB/4/edit

This is the best I've been able to do.
I got rid of Codemirror, and used a regular textbox/textarea.
I set it all up in a form for easier callbacks.
I could not figure out how to callback an onchange or onkeyup event for the iframe. So instead I call it back by toggling the textbox.

```
window.onload = function() {
  preview.document.designMode = 'On';
  preview.document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, "false");
  preview.document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", false, "false");
};

// Calls code from preview to textbox
function submit_form() {
  var theForm = document.getElementById("container");
  theForm.elements.code.value = window.frames.preview.document.body.innerHTML;
  theForm.onclick();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var code = $('#code'),
    preview = $('[ID$=preview]');

  // Live Debugging
  code.keyup(IntPrev);

  function IntPrev(e) {
    preview.contents().find('body').html(code.val());
  }

  // Toggle between Designer and Code
  $("#design-n-code").click(function() {
    preview.toggle();
    code.toggle();
  }); code.hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Via 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames

I've next to no experience with codemirror, but raw DOM allows access to iframes using `Window.frames[]`.  If you pull the data back in through dom using `.addEventListener("onchange",function)`, you should be able to work with it.

If this answer isn't specific enough (or out of scope, since I don't know a way to do this inside of your framework), please provide me with what exactly you're trying to pull back, and i'll do some more research.